# How to add menu item on dashboard menu in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying the following syntax to add the custom menu on dashboard. and I put this code in 'function.php' in theme folder file. but its not displaying menu on dashboard. So, please help me in which file I put this code? otherwise any other solution please help me.

```
<?php 
  add_action( 'admin_menu', 'register_my_custom_menu_page' );
  function register_my_custom_menu_page(){ 
       add_menu_page( 'custom menu title', 'custom    menu', 'manage_options', 'custompage', 'my_custom_menu_page', plugins_url( 'myplugin/images/icon.png' ), 6 ); 
  }
  function my_custom_menu_page(){
      echo "Admin Page Test";   
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In which function.php file are you writing this code? are you writing in the core files? if you are writing in the theme's function file just make sure that the theme is currently active.